# PageIndex not getting set from Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set page index when user is on a particular page and does sorting on that index only. But even when on putting in PageIndex value manually, PageIndex always sets to 1. What to do?

```
function LoadUser(columnname, sort, IsClient) {
            var className = $('#' + columnname).attr('class');
            IsClient = $('#ChkIsClient').is(':checked')
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
            url: "/admin/Setting/UserGrid",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            data: { PageIndex: 2, filter: $("#txtSearchUser").val(), SortColumnName: columnname, sort: sort, IsClient: IsClient },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#Setting_content').html("");
                $('#Setting_content').html(response);

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

My Controller

```
   public ActionResult UserGrid(int PageIndex = 1,  string filter = "", string SortColumnName = "", string Sort = "asc", bool IsClient = true)
    {
        int pageSize = Common.PageSize();
        UserServiceReference.UserServiceClient UserService = new UserServiceReference.UserServiceClient();
        if (Sort != "N")
        {
            if (_Usersortcolumn == SortColumnName && _usercounter == 0)
                _sortcolumn = SortColumnName + "_desc";
            else
                _sortcolumn = SortColumnName + "_asc";
        }
        if (SortColumnName != "")
            _usercounter++;
        if (_usercounter >= 2) _usercounter = 0;
        ViewBag.Search = filter.Trim();
        _Usersortcolumn = SortColumnName;
        ViewBag.Sort = SortColumnName;
        if (ViewBag.IsClient != null) ViewBag.IsClient = IsClient;
        else ViewBag.IsClient = IsClient;
        var result = UserService.UserList(filter.Trim(), _sortcolumn, Sort, IsClient);
        IPagedList<UserListModel> UserPageList = null;
        List<UserListModel> _UserDataModal = new List<UserListModel>();
        foreach (var u in result)
        {
            UserListModel ObjUser = new UserListModel();
            ObjUser.ID = u.Id;
            ObjUser.UserName = u.UserName;
            ObjUser.Name = u.Name;
            ObjUser.DepartmentName = u.DepartmentName;
            ObjUser.RoleName = u.RoleName;
            ObjUser.Nets = u.Nets;
            _UserDataModal.Add(ObjUser);
        }
        UserPageList = _UserDataModal.ToPagedList(PageIndex, pageSize);
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest() == true)
        {
            return PartialView("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Setting/Partial/_UserGrid.cshtml", UserPageList);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("~/Areas/Admin/Views/Setting/Partial/_UserGrid.cshtml", UserPageList);
        }
    }
```

my view

```
<a href="#" onclick="UserAddEdit.LoadUser('name','desc')">Name</a><span><i id="name" class=""></i></span>
```

I don't understand what is wrong. Even when putting in the page index, it doesn't work and it still takes the value 1. ie the default value.